# Chrome Extension: remote api and parse the received JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extensions, that call remote API and I need to read a JSON data but it does not work to parse the data?
The Jquery should be included in "background:" of manifest attribute?
If yes, How?
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/lquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 8,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "p",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],

      "js": [ "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
      "64":"icon.png"
      },
  "permissions": [
      "http://domain.com/*"
    ]

}
```

background.js

```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "http://domain.com/api/path", false);
    xhr.send();

            var result = xhr.responseText;
           //var result = eval('(' + xhr.responseText + ')');

    alert(result);//work print json data
    alert(result.results[1].url);// does not work
```

recived json data

```
{"results":[
{"name":"Academic","url":"http:\/\/www.rapidintellect.com\/AEQweb\/"},{"name":"Academy","url":"http:\/\/aocrj.org\/"}
]} {"results":[
{"name2":"Academic","url":"http:\/\/www.rapidintellect.com\/AEQweb\/"},{"name2":"Academy","url":"http:\/\/aocrj.org\/"}
]}
```

Comment: You're not using jQuery?

Comment: What is the output of second `alert`?

Comment: I do not use any jquery

Comment: when I remove the first alert and keep the second alert nothing happen "no alert display"

Answer (score 1):

You can parse JSON to an `Object` in JavaScript with the `JSON.parse` function:

```
var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
alert(result.results[0].url);
```

I'm not sure your initial Ajax request is valid though.

Considering you tagged this question with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), we can simplify the Ajax request, and automatically parse the JSON:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://example.com/...',
  dataType: 'json',
}).success(function(result){
  alert(result.results[1].url)
});
```

Or, since this is a simple GET request, you can use something even more shorthand:

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/...', function(result){
  alert(result.results[1].url)
});
```

Comment: @Seham: Try the jQuery examples.

Comment: How to add jQuery "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/lquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" in manifest ?

Comment: Download it (right-click and save) to your extension's folder.  Then change your manifest to include it, like `"scripts": [ "jquery.min.js", "background.js" ]`

Comment: I download the file from https://blog.jquery.com/2014/05/01/jquery-1-11-1-and-2-1-1-released/ ......then I save it in my extension folder as "jquery.min.js" ..... but still not work ... I really appreciate your time :)